# in Android Q, how to tracking an application's network statistics (rx and tx)

Tags: android, networking, statistics, privacy, android-10.0

in Android Q, how to tracking an application's network statistics (rx and tx) . not getting rx and tx in android 10 using below code.Its working up to pie without any probs

```
     while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // Parse the network traffic statistics pertaining to this connection
            DataInputStream in = null;
            try {

               in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("/proc/net/dev"));
                final String prefix = "tun0" + ':';
                while (true) {
                    String line = in.readLine().trim();
                    if (line.startsWith(prefix)) {
                        String[] numbers = line.substring(prefix.length()).split(" +");

                        boolean foundNonZero = false;
                        for (int i = 1; i < 17 && foundNonZero == false; ++i) {

                            if (!numbers[i].equals("0")) {
                                foundNonZero = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (foundNonZero) {
                            rxBytes = numbers[NET_INTERFACE_BYTES_IN_COL];
                            txBytes = numbers[NET_INTERFACE_BYTES_OUT_COL];
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            } finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
```

Comment: `TrafficStats` has been around for years.

Comment: But its keep on changing each second eve without acces  network.is there any other solutions wen i using vpn?